# Как выводить диалоговое окно при запуске приложения?

Tags: android

Часто в приложениях после обновления вылазило диалоговое окно с описанием самого обновления. 
В меню настроек могу выводить диалоговое окно с нужной информацией с помощью alertdialog, но как сделать так что бы диалоговое окно выскакивало при запуске?
При необходимости могу предоставить код

Comment: просто в onCreate() первого Activity вызывайте показ диалога, в чем проблема?

Comment: ну кстати лучше не в Create это делать, есть вероятность что UI тяжелый можно схватить ex, маленькая вероятность канеш, и то если это не фрагмент, как рекомендуют делать, но все же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам класс, коий проверяет показывался ли диалог с новыми фичами для этой версии приложения и если нет, то отображающий его.

Просто вызовите в главной активити метод проверки,

```
NewVersionFeachersDialog.appLaunched(this);
```

И допишите показ собственно диалога в конец класса, там где //TODO

```
public class NewVersionFeachersDialog
{
    public static void appLaunched(Context ctx)
    {
        PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
        String app_ver = "";
        try
        {
            app_ver = pm.getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

            Log.i("app_ver", app_ver);

            SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(app_ver, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (prefs.getBoolean(ActivityPreference.PREF_KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH, false) == true)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(ActivityPreference.PREF_KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH, true);
                editor.commit();
                showNewVersionDialog(ctx);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    public static void showNewVersionDialog(final Context ctx)
    {
        PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
        String app_ver = "";
        try
        {
            app_ver = pm.getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }

        String message = "new versionFeatures"; //заполните строку нужными данными и задайте её как текст диалогу

        //TODO тут отобразите диалог с вашим сообщением
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня что то ничего не получается